# How do I show that the set of probability distributions that first/second-order stochastically dominate p is closed and convex?

Tags: microeconomics

I was trying to understand stochastic dominance when I came across [this problem (Question 2)](http://www.econ.ucla.edu/iobara/ps52010.pdf). How do I show that the set of probability distributions that first/second-order stochastically dominate $p$ is closed and convex?

I have attempted to solve the set of FOSD is convex; but how do I show that the "limit" of probability distributions is also in the set (i.e. the set is closed)?

Comment: Please make your question selfcontained.